# Variance of Function involving random variable and its conditional expectation

Tags: probability, statistics

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$
$\newcommand{\Cov}{\operatorname{Cov}}$

I am supposed to show the following:

$$
\Var(Y-E(Y\mid X)) = E(\Var(Y\mid X))
$$

My attempt involved using simple property of conditional expectations and variances, I get a close result, but not quite:

$$
\Var(Y-E(Y\mid X)) = \Var(Y) + \Var(E(Y\mid X)) - 2\Cov(Y,E(Y\mid X))
$$

Since $\Cov(Y,E(Y\mid X)) = \Cov(Y,Y) = \Var(Y)$, then:

$$
\Var(Y) + \Var(E(Y\mid X)) - 2\Cov(Y,E(Y\mid X)) = \Var(E(Y\mid X)) - \Var(Y)
$$

But $\Var(Y) = \Var(E(Y\mid X)) - E(\Var(Y\mid X))$ and then:

$$
\Var(E(Y\mid X)) - \Var(Y) = \Var(E(Y\mid X)) - \Var(E(Y\mid X)) - E(\Var(Y\mid X)) = -E(\Var(Y\mid X))
$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well-known problem.  Note

$$V(Y\mid X) = E(Y^2\mid X) - ((E(Y\mid X))^2$$

such that

$$EV(Y\mid X) = E(Y^2) -  ((E(Y\mid X))^2.$$

Now, since $E((Y-E(Y\mid X))=0$ by the law of iterated expectations,

$$V(Y-E(Y\mid X))=
E(Y^2 - 2 Y E(Y\mid X) + (E(Y\mid X))^2) = E(Y^2) - (E(Y\mid X))^2,$$

again by the law of iterated expectations.  Done.

Comment: Ok, I see it. But where does my reasoning break down?

Comment: $Cov(Y,E(Y|X)) = E(Y E(Y|X)) - E(Y) E(E(Y|X))= E(E(Y|X))^2 - (E(Y))^2 \neq V(Y)$